# Java threading issue, I am getting a null, while executing a async task

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a async return for a time consuming task. So task data is inserted in a Q, and return immediately. A bunch of 20 threads take tasks from that data queue. But the data in thread is getting null, I wonder why.

Code segment's (only relevant parts of code)

Definition

```
private static LinkedList<Object[]> cacheQ = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
private static ArrayList<Thread> cacheThreads = null;
```

One time initialization

```
if (cacheThreads == null) {
        cacheThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            CacheThread cacheThread = readWriteOps.new CacheThread();
            Thread thread = new Thread(cacheThread);
            cacheThreads.add(i, thread);
            thread.start();
        }
        System.out.println("CAche Threads Started!");
    }
```

Adding a new task to the Q at the beginning (`addFirst`)

```
public void arrayizeToCache(String key, CacheData value) {
    synchronized (cacheThreads) {
        Object[] tuple = new Object[SIZE] ;
        tuple[KEY] = key ;
        tuple[VALUE] = value ;
----NOT NULL----log.debug("CacheThread arrayizeToCache k"+key+"v"+value) ;
        cacheQ.addFirst((Object[])tuple);
        cacheThreads.notify();
    }
}
```

The actual work of the thread

```
public class CacheThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("CachedThread running!");
        CacheData cacheStore = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                String key;
                synchronized (cacheThreads) {
                    if (cacheQ.isEmpty()) {
                        log.debug("Cache Q waiting");
                        cacheThreads.wait();
                    }
                    if (cacheQ.isEmpty()) {
                        log.error("Cache List empty nothing to cache");
                        continue;
                    }
                    Object[] cacheData = (Object[]) cacheQ.removeLast();
                    key = (String) cacheData[KEY] ;
                    cacheStore = (CacheData) cacheData[VALUE];
----- HERE -----
//More code, but irrelevant for this question. 
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // log.debug(((Runnable) this).toString() +
            // "Server : flush SUCCESS");
        }
    }
}
```

At `-----HERE-----` I am getting a null for `cacheStore.getValue()`. What am I missing here. Something basic.

I have used a LinkedList, for the Q, so structurally it should work. The linkedlist holds the data which I need to process. It holds a Object array since I have more than 1 data element.

Edit :

```
private static final int KEY = 0 ;
private static final int VALUE = 1 ;
private static final int SIZE = 2 ;
```

Edit Again : 
This is how I am calling arrayize

```
ReadWriteOperations.getInstance(this).arrayizeToCache(key,
            new CacheData(subscription, SuperCache.NEVER_EXPIRE));
```

My CacheData object

```
public class CacheData {
private Object value ;
private Integer expiry = 0 ;
public CacheData(Object newValue) {
    value = newValue ;
}
public CacheData (Object newValue, Integer newExpiry) {
// THIS LINE WAS MISSING        value = newValue ;
    expiry = newExpiry ;
}
public Object getValue() {
    return value ;
}
public Integer getExpiry () {
    return expiry ;
}
}
```

Answer : I was initializing value at all. Kinda assumed that it will be a more complex thing. And its 2am here :) Thanks to @Gray.

Comment: You should consider using an `ExecutorService` for this.  By forking your own threads and then reading from a job queue, you are in effect rewriting them.   See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Comment: If you don't move to an `ExecutorService`, you should switch your `cacheQ` queue to be a `BlockingQueue` which takes care of the synchronized, notify/wait, etc..

Comment: I changed linkedlist to ConcurrentLinked and your LinkedBlockingQueue, both did not work. Same result. Something else is the matter here.

Comment: Where is cacheStore's value updated?  Is it updated _after_ the threads are started?  Is it updated inside of a `synchronized (cacheThreads) {` block?

Comment: it is updated inside the synchrnized (cachethreads) block

Comment: Can you also please print Queue size when you are retreiving values, just to verify nulls are not being added somewhere by mistake ? Also, are you getting key also null or its just that only values in null ?

Comment: @Gray good hints, thanks. I fixed it. Will post the root cause shortly. In the meanwhile, please put out a answer, so that I may reciprocate the favor by a upvote and accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.  I would be interested to know:

- Where is cacheStore's value updated?
- Is it updated after the threads are started?  This may be the problem.
- If so, it needs to be updated inside of a `synchronized (cacheThreads) {` block for the changes to be visible to the running threads.

Here are some additional comments about the code:

- You are forking your own threads and then having a `synchronized` `LinkedList` for the jobs.  I would encourage you to look into the [`ExecutorService` patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) that do both of those for.  Definitely recommended for most threading tasks.
- If you don't move to an `ExecutorService`, you should switch your `cacheQ` queue to be a `BlockingQueue` which takes care of the `synchronized`, `notify()`/`wait()`, etc. for you.

Comment: Here you go, thanks again. I can sleep now, and fix the client issue tomorrow.